# Why PySimpleGUI with subprocess crashed on Window7

Tags: python, windows, crash, pysimplegui

I'm new to PySimpleGUI. When I use module subprocess and packaged py into exe, it always crash like screenshot below. But when I run my py file direct in cmd, it just fine. So anyone please tell me how to fix it? thx.

Exe file crash on Windows7 when click ok:
[image]

run script in CLI when click ok:
[image]

SimpleDemoSubprocess Test.py:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess


def runCommand(cmd, timeout=None):
    """ run shell command
    @param cmd: command to execute
    @param timeout: timeout for command execution
    @return: (return code from command, command output)
    """

    prt('runCommand, cmd = ' + str(cmd))

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = ''

    prt('runCommand, communicate')
    out, err = p.communicate()
    prt('runCommand, wait')
    p.wait(timeout)

    prt(out)
    prt(err)
    sg.Popup(out)


    return (out, err)


def prt(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None):
    print()
    print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\r\n', file=None)


# All the stuff inside your window.
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Some text on Row 1')]
    , [sg.Text('Enter something on Row 2'), sg.InputText()]
    , [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Cancel')]
    # , [sg.PopupScrolled('Hello From PySimpleGUI!', 'This is the shortest GUI program ever!')]
]

# Create the Window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)
# Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (None, 'Cancel'):  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        break
    if event in (None, 'Ok'):  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        runCommand("ls")
    print('You entered ', values[0])

window.close()
```

package py into exe:

```
# https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_EXE_Maker.py

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess
from shutil import copyfile
import shutil
import os

def prt(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None):
    print()
    print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\r\n', file=None)

def Launcher():
    sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('LightGreen')

    layout = [[sg.T('PyInstaller EXE Creator', font='Any 15')],
              [sg.T('Source Python File'), sg.In(key='_sourcefile_', size=(45, 1)),
               sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Python Files", "*.py"),))],
              [sg.T('Icon File'), sg.In(key='_iconfile_', size=(45, 1)),
               sg.FileBrowse(file_types=(("Icon Files", "*.ico"),))],
              [sg.Frame('Output', font='Any 15', layout=[[sg.Output(size=(65, 15), font='Courier 10')]])],
              [sg.ReadFormButton('Make EXE', bind_return_key=True),
               sg.SimpleButton('Quit', button_color=('white', 'firebrick3')), ]]

    window = sg.Window('PySimpleGUI EXE Maker',
                       auto_size_text=False,
                       auto_size_buttons=False,
                       default_element_size=(20, 1,),
                       text_justification='right')

    window.Layout(layout)

    # ---===--- Loop taking in user input --- #
    while True:
        (button, values) = window.Read()
        if button in ('Quit', None):
            break  # exit button clicked

        source_file = values['_sourcefile_']
        icon_file = values['_iconfile_']

        icon_option = '-i "{}"'.format(icon_file) if icon_file else ''
        source_path, source_filename = os.path.split(source_file)
        workpath_option = '--workpath "{}"'.format(source_path)
        dispath_option = '--distpath "{}"'.format(source_path)
        specpath_option = '--specpath "{}"'.format(source_path)
        folder_to_remove = os.path.join(source_path, source_filename[:-3])
        file_to_remove = os.path.join(source_path, source_filename[:-3] + '.spec')
        command_line = 'pyinstaller -wF "{}" {} {} {} {}'.format(source_file, icon_option, workpath_option,
                                                                 dispath_option, specpath_option)

        if button == 'Make EXE':
            try:
                prt('source_file: ' + str(source_file))
                prt('Making EXE... this will take a while.. the program has NOT locked up...')
                window.Refresh()

                prt('window.Refresh')
                window.Refresh()
                prt('Running command: {}'.format(command_line))
                runCommand(command_line)
                shutil.rmtree(folder_to_remove)
                os.remove(file_to_remove)
                prt('**** DONE ****')
            except Exception as e:
                # sg.PopupError('Something went wrong')
                prt("Launcher, Exception = " + e)


def runCommand(cmd, timeout=None):
    """ run shell command
    @param cmd: command to execute
    @param timeout: timeout for command execution
    @return: (return code from command, command output)
    """

    prt('runCommand, cmd = ' + str(cmd))

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = ''

    prt('runCommand, communicate')
    out, err = p.communicate()
    prt('runCommand, wait')
    p.wait(timeout)

    prt(out)
    prt(err)

    return (out, err)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Launcher()
```

Comment: run exe in console to see if you get error message. Often programs which create exe can't find all needed modules and program can't load some module.

Comment: @furas, sorry for your misunderstanding. Exe is fine, only the ok button crashed by calling subprocess. Is this kind of crash can be printed in console too?

Comment: you don't know what kind or crash you have so always run code in console to see if you don't get error message. And exe can start correctly but it may crash because it doesn't have some element which subprocess may need - and this can be problem with program which you used to create .exe.

Comment: Ok, I tested, it is fine in CLI. so It must be the py-exe packge, how can I fix it? as it is official packge code which copy form official site.

Comment: don't you get any error in CLI when it crash?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post, My 'CLI' means run in python command.  I'm newbie in windows dev, and don't know how to print exe crash in console. sorry

Comment: open CLI and run `Test.exe` instead of `python Test.py`

Comment: your CLI is also called `console`, `terminal`, `cmd.exe`, `DOS`

Comment: Ok, I got. I executed 'c:\Test.exe' in cmd.exe, and it did not print any logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved by changing to this:

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)